# Declaring the local variable in Oracle by using declare

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql

In MS SQL and Sybase, we assign the count of the query to the variable as shown below.

```
declare @rate_count int
select count(1) "Count"  =   @rate_count
from 
(select DISTINCT RATE_CODE from APPROVED_RATE RATE
where RATE.RATE_CHNG_IND = 'Y')
```

Whereas, in oracle, I can't even declare? Any help
Because depends on the value return, While loop starts like

```
while (@rate_count > 1)
Begin
--

End
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can declare ..

```
Declare 

rate_count number; 

begin 

select count(1) into rate_count
from 
(select DISTINCT RATE_CODE from APPROVED_RATE RATE
where RATE.RATE_CHNG_IND = 'Y');


dmbs_output.put_line(rate_count);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use like the following in Oracle :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare 
 rate_count int;
begin 
 select count(1) "Count" into rate_count from (select DISTINCT RATE_CODE from APPROVED_RATE RATE where RATE.RATE_CHNG_IND = 'Y');
 dbms_output.put_line('Your Rate Count is : '||rate_count);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't allow us to execute SQL statements in the `declare` section of a block. So what you need to do is:

```
declare 
    rate_count pls_integer;
begin
    select count(DISTINCT RATE_CODE) 
    into rate_count 
    from APPROVED_RATE RATE
    where RATE.RATE_CHNG_IND = 'Y';

    while rate_count > 1 loop
        ....
```

Be careful with that WHILE. Unless you decrement `rate_count` or have some other EXIT condition the code will loop for ever. Perhaps what you meant is:

```
for idx in 1 .. rate_count loop
```